# Azure Databricks pipeline failing because of dependency

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

we have a Databricks Pipeline which runs every 6 hours most of the time it runs successfully but sometimes its getting failed by throwing below error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<module-name>'
```

I am new to Databricks can anyone tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Could you please provide the name of the module in your error.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT module is `pyodbc`

Comment: If you add a ```pip install pyodbc``` on your notebook, it may work. Else, please try to restart the cluster or re-install the ```pyodbc``` library.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT I have checked the runtime and library is present in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the dependent libraries will not be working fine is base environment. It's highly suggestable to create virtual environment.

Follow the link to create virtual environment in Data Bricks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/runtime/conda

Refer the following link to connect pyodbc with databricks.

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/pyodbc.html